# Python: get the names of specific file types in a given folder

Tags: python, csv, path, directory, filenames

I have a folder which contains `n` `csv` files, and they are all named `event_1.csv`, `event_2.csv`, all the way up to `event_n.csv`.

I want to be able to `raw_input` their folder path and then retrieve their names, *file extension excluded*.

I tried to do it but I only get printed the folder path as many times as there are `csv` files in it. The filenames are never printed, instead, and they are what I want.

This is the best I have come up with so far, but it does the wrong thing:

```
import os
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
for i,file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        print os.path.basename(directoryPath)
```

where `directoryPath=C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\myfolder`, in which there are three files: `event_1.csv`, `event_2.csv`, `event_3.csv`.

What I get is:

```
myfolder
myfolder
myfolder
```

What I want, instead, is:

```
event_1
event_2
event_3
```

PS: I expect to have as many as 100 files. Therefore I should be able to include situations like these, where the filename is longer:

```
event_10
event_100
```

**EDIT**

What can I add to make sure the files are read exactly in the same order as they are named? This means: first read `event_1.csv`, then `event_2.csv`, and so forth until I reach `event_100.csv`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are getting what you ask for. See this line in your code:

```
print os.path.basename(directoryPath)
```

It prints the `directoryPath`.

I think it should be:

```
import os
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
for i,file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        print os.path.basename(file)
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**:

Let's create a list of all file names without path and extension (l). Now:

```
for n in sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1])):
    print n
```

Now you need to write your specific solution :)

Comment: You can add a sort function on the list of files, that sorts the part you'd like to sort. Note that strings are sorted differently than numbers (i.e. '100' is smaller than '3').

Comment: I added an example of such sorting.